# What is the difference between TPG and Tournament Performance Rating?

Tags: rating, tournament

wI understand "Tournament Performance Rating", but I have seen a [Web calculator](https://www.englishchess.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/CalculatorPage.html) that also has TPG. What is the difference between them and why are both used?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "TPG" and what the context is? What does TPG stand for? If TPG is ECF related and stands for "Tournament performance grade" then you should note that it is out of date. The ECF no longer uses 3-figure "grades" calculated using their own rather old grading system dating back to the 1950's. They have recently changed completely to use 4-figure Elo ratings.

Comment: And a link to the calculator won't hurt either. I'm leaving it open since the answer seems to be right, so apparently it's not 'unclear' enough.

Comment: @Glorfindel I added the link, it seems to be some odd English system.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.englishchess.org.uk/Juniors/tournament-performance-calculator/

"The tournament performance grade (TPG) commonly used in the ECF grading system is calculated on a different basis than a TPR.  Junior selection TPGs, however, are essentially TPR calculations using FIDE ratings that correspond to ECF grades."